# Updating / working with Server 2008 - non-r2

Tags: windows-server-2008, citrix, xenapp, 32-bit

I have a client that needs to install Citrix XenApp 6.5 on a server 2008 32bit, non-r2 VM.  When attempting the install, it states I need .Net 3.5, but crashes after the install attempt.

I attempt a windows update figuring that will work, but even though I have not run any updates on this VM, it states they are up to date.  Can't even load IE 9 onto it without the install crashing.

Wondering if dealing with win 2008 32bit non-r2 is THAT difficult to work with?  Any suggestions on getting XenApp 6.5 on it is appreciated.

Comment: Manually installed .net 3.5. Having issues finding documentation though if XenApp 6.5 needs to be on a R2 server or not.

Comment: Server 2008 (non-R2) is based on Vista's code base, which can be the source of that grief. I would look into the install logs as to why .NET 3.5 is crashing, and also check the logs for why Windows is unable to update.

Comment: In general, if the documentation does not specify 2008 R2, it means just 2008.  2008 R2 is a very different operating system, in the same way Windows 7 is very different from Windows Vista.

Comment: XA65 is 64 bit only. (So it will not run on 2008r1x86.) See comment thread on [this official Citrix blog post](https://www.citrix.com/blogs/2011/08/24/new-xenapp-6-5-available-now/) See also: *Getting Started with Citrix XenApp 6.5* book: [*System requirements* page](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/getting-started-with/9781849686662/ch01s03.html)

Comment: Stop what you're doing. XenApp 6.5 most definitely **only** supports Windows Server 2008 R2 which, as @StackzOfZtuff states, is inherently 64-bit - see XA 6.5 [system requirements](http://docs.citrix.com/en-us/xenapp-and-xendesktop/xenapp-6-5/xenapp65-w2k8-wrapper/ps-system-requirements-w2k8-xa65.html). Even if you somehow manage to convince it to install to a 2008 non-R2, best case you will an unsupported configuration, and worst (and extremely likely) a setup that does not work properly or at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would investigate the logs of both [Windows Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/902093) and of the logs of [.NET 3.5 installer.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/07/31/4156781.aspx) in order to get a clearer picture of the issue.

If .NET is determined to be the issue, I would recommend reviewing the information in this [treasure trove of .NET troubleshooting information.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2005/08/22/unified-net-framework-troubleshooting-guide.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, seems from the windowsupdate log that I download and installed a Checked Build from technet.  So cant apply an update if I wanted.  Time to scrap this and start over.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Stop what you're doing.

XenApp 6.5 most definitely **only** supports Windows Server 2008 R2 which, as @StackzOfZtuff states, is inherently 64-bit - see XA 6.5 [system requirements](http://docs.citrix.com/en-us/xenapp-and-xendesktop/xenapp-6-5/xenapp65-w2k8-wrapper/ps-system-requirements-w2k8-xa65.html).

Even if you through black magic somehow manage to convince it to install to a 2008 non-R2, best case you will an unsupported configuration, but worst (and extremely likely) a setup that does not work properly or at all.